# Prove using Schur decomposition $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}||A^n||=0 \iff p(A)<1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, limits, spectral-radius, schur-decomposition

a) Prove using Schur decomposition $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}||A^n||=0 \iff p(A)<1$ where A is in $\mathbb{C}^{mxm}$ and $p$ is the spectral radius.

b) $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}||e^{At}||=0 \iff a(A)<1$ where A is in $\mathbb{C}^{mxm}$ and $a$ is the spectral abscissa.

My thoughts are as follows. For (a), I think that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}||A^n||=0$ will only happen if the matrix A is nilpotent. But if the matrix is nilpotent then wouldn't $p(A)=0$ which is less than 1 but I feel like I am missing something.

Comment: The matrix $A={1 \over 2}$ is not nilpotent but $A^n \to 0$.

Comment: oh thank you. I see what you mean. I will think about that.

Comment: I think I see how to do that now. Thank you @copper.hat

Comment: thanks you're right